# How to prevent pandas from changing a multiindex DataFrame structure during JSON conversion?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe initially:

```
cat   cat    1  1  1  1  1
      dog    0  0  0  0  0
      fox    0  0  0  0  0
      jumps  1  1  1  1  1
      mouse  1  1  1  1  1
      over   1  1  1  1  1
      the    1  1  1  1  1
dog   cat    0  0  0  0  0
      dog    1  1  1  1  1
      fox    1  1  1  1  1
      jumps  1  1  1  1  1
      mouse  0  0  0  0  0
      over   1  1  1  1  1
      the    1  1  1  1  1
fox   cat    0  0  0  0  0
      dog    1  1  1  1  1
      fox    1  1  1  1  1
      jumps  1  1  1  1  1
      mouse  0  0  0  0  0
      over   1  1  1  1  1
      the    1  1  1  1  1
jumps cat    1  1  1  1  1
      dog    1  1  1  1  1
      fox    1  1  1  1  1
      jumps  1  1  1  1  1
      mouse  1  1  1  1  1
      over   1  0  1  1  1
      the    1  0  1  1  1
mouse cat    1  1  1  1  1
      dog    0  0  0  0  0
      fox    0  0  0  0  0
      jumps  1  1  1  1  1
      mouse  1  1  1  1  1
      over   1  1  1  1  1
      the    1  1  1  1  1
over  cat    1  1  1  1  1
      dog    1  1  1  1  1
      fox    1  1  1  1  1
      jumps  1  1  0  1  0
      mouse  1  1  1  1  1
      over   1  1  1  1  1
      the    1  0  1  1  1
the   cat    1  1  1  1  1
      dog    1  1  1  1  1
      fox    1  1  1  1  1
      jumps  1  1  0  1  1
      mouse  1  1  1  1  1
      over   1  1  0  1  0
      the    1  1  1  1  1
```

Then I convert it into JSON format using the following:

```
JSON = df.reset_index().to_json()
```

(reset_index() because you can't convert multiindex df to JSON directly)

Then I revert it back to DataFrame() format using the following:

```
new_df = pd.read_json(JSON)
```

But now when I print it, it shows the following dataframe:

```
0   1  1  1  1  1     cat     cat
1   0  0  0  0  0     cat     dog
10  1  1  1  1  1     dog   jumps
11  0  0  0  0  0     dog   mouse
12  1  1  1  1  1     dog    over
13  1  1  1  1  1     dog     the
14  0  0  0  0  0     fox     cat
15  1  1  1  1  1     fox     dog
16  1  1  1  1  1     fox     fox
17  1  1  1  1  1     fox   jumps
18  0  0  0  0  0     fox   mouse
19  1  1  1  1  1     fox    over
2   0  0  0  0  0     cat     fox
20  1  1  1  1  1     fox     the
21  1  1  1  1  1   jumps     cat
22  1  1  1  1  1   jumps     dog
23  1  1  1  1  1   jumps     fox
24  1  1  1  1  1   jumps   jumps
25  1  1  1  1  1   jumps   mouse
26  1  0  1  1  1   jumps    over
27  1  0  1  1  1   jumps     the
28  1  1  1  1  1   mouse     cat
29  0  0  0  0  0   mouse     dog
3   1  1  1  1  1     cat   jumps
30  0  0  0  0  0   mouse     fox
31  1  1  1  1  1   mouse   jumps
32  1  1  1  1  1   mouse   mouse
33  1  1  1  1  1   mouse    over
34  1  1  1  1  1   mouse     the
35  1  1  1  1  1    over     cat
36  1  1  1  1  1    over     dog
37  1  1  1  1  1    over     fox
38  1  1  0  1  0    over   jumps
39  1  1  1  1  1    over   mouse
4   1  1  1  1  1     cat   mouse
40  1  1  1  1  1    over    over
41  1  0  1  1  1    over     the
42  1  1  1  1  1     the     cat
43  1  1  1  1  1     the     dog
44  1  1  1  1  1     the     fox
45  1  1  0  1  1     the   jumps
46  1  1  1  1  1     the   mouse
47  1  1  0  1  0     the    over
48  1  1  1  1  1     the     the
5   1  1  1  1  1     cat    over
6   1  1  1  1  1     cat     the
7   0  0  0  0  0     dog     cat
8   1  1  1  1  1     dog     dog
9   1  1  1  1  1     dog     fox
```

As you can see the structure has been completely changed. Is there any way I can keep exactly the same structure of my Dataframe during conversion to and from JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You have the index here just adding `sort_index`

```
pd.read_json(JSON).sort_index()
```

Comment: This doesn't work, still the df remains structually damaged

Comment: @Elisha512 after you reset_index before to_json ,  the df remains structually damaged

Comment: Is there anyway to save it JSON without damaging the structure?

Comment: @Elisha512 you know you can convert it back right ?

Comment: @Elisha512 pd.read_json(JSON).sort_index().set_index(['level_0','level_1'])